# Finding the row indices of a logical vector without using find()

Tags: matlab, optimization

My program handles huge amount of data and the function `find` is the one to blame for taking so much time to execute. At some point I get a logical vector and I want to extract row indices of the 1 elements in the vector. How can I do that without using the find function?

Here's a demo:

```
temp = rand(10000000, 1);
temp1 = temp > 0.5;
temp2 = find(temp1);
```

But it is too slow in case of having much more data. Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's the amount of data?

Comment: A similar operation will be done on a data set with the size 30000 x 14 for more than 1 million times ...

Comment: Do you really need to use find? Coudn't you replace it by [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66992-logical-indexing-is-usually-faster-than-find)?

Comment: How can I do that? I need the indices where I have 1 in the logical vector ``temp1``

Comment: Let's follow your code sample: suppose you have the indices on `temp2`. Now, suppose you use those indexes to access elements on, lets say, `temp`, like this: `temp(temp2) = 0`. You could do it directly like this: `temp(temp > 0.5) = 0`. That is, you could use the logical vector directly, without the need to use `find` to get the indexes. But that depends on what you'll do with those indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Find` seems to be a very optimized function. What I did was to create a `mex` version very restricted to this particular problem. Running time was cut by half. :)

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxLogical *in;
    double *out;
    int i, nInput, nTrues;

    // Get the number of elements of the input.
    nInput = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);

    // Get a pointer to the logical input array.
    in = mxGetLogicals(prhs[0]);    

    // Allocate memory for the output. As we don't know the number of
    // matches, we allocate an array the same size of the input. We will
    // probably reallocate it later.
    out = mxMalloc(sizeof(double) * nInput);

    // Count the number of 'trues' and store its positions.
    for (nTrues = 0, i = 0; i < nInput; )
        if (in[i++])
            out[nTrues++] = i;

    // Reallocate the array, if necessary.
    if (nTrues < nInput)
        out = mxRealloc(out, sizeof(double) * nTrues);

    // Assign the indexes to the output array.
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0, 0, mxREAL);
    mxSetPr(plhs[0], out);
    mxSetM(plhs[0], nTrues);
    mxSetN(plhs[0], 1);
}
```

Just save it to a file called, for example, `find2.c` and compile with `mex find2.c`.

Assuming:

```
temp = rand(10000000, 1);
temp1 = temp > 0.5;
```

Running times:

```
tic
temp2 = find(temp1);
toc
```

**Elapsed time is 0.082875 seconds.**

```
tic
temp2 = find2(temp1);
toc
```

**Elapsed time is 0.044330 seconds.**

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** this function has no error handling. It's assumed the input is always a logical array and the output is a double array. Caution is required.

Comment: If you want to make it faster, do the comparison in the mex, i.e. for each element in temp, check if it is >0.5, then save its index if it is. This means you only drag a 10^7 long vector through memory once, rather than twice.

Comment: Sure. First, follow [this instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html). After the compiler is set, just type `mex find2.c` and use the `find2` function as in the example. It's a good idea to learn how to create those C++ interfaces with Matlab, you can improve performance a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to split your calculations in small pieces. This will not reduce the amount of calculations you have to do, but it might still be faster since the data fits into fast cache memory, instead of in the slow main memory (or in the worst case you might even be swapping to disk). Something like this:

```
temp = rand(10000000, 1);
n = 100000; % chunk size
for i = 1:floor(length(temp) / n)
    chunk = temp(((i-1) * n + 1):(i*n))
    temp1 = chunk > 0.5;
    temp2 = find(temp1);
    do_stuff(temp2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of regular index and then apply logical indexing. I didn't check if it was faster than `find` tough.

Example:

```
Index=1:size(temp);
Found = Index(temp1);
```

Comment: Nice! But I've tested it here and, unfortunatelly, it's slower (takes almost twice the time).